# Select and Extract spatial attributes in R

Tags: r, select-by-attribute, sf

I want to select features in a polygon shapefile on the basis of a selection criteria. In ArcGIS, one can do selection by attribute and then export selected data as shapefile. How can the same be done using the `sf` package in `R`?

```
   MultiPoly_Shp = st_read("path/MultiPoly_Shp.shp")
    List = c(33,35,36,37,50,54,57,59,60,61,62,63,64,66,67,69,70,71,76,78,80,90,93,97,98,99,100,101,102,106,107,108,111,112,115,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,127,128,147,148,152,153)
    Multipoly_Select = dplyr::select(MultiPoly_Shp$ID != List) 

# Export Multipoly_Select as .shp
```

Error

```
Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "logical"
In addition: Warning message:
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Maybe `dplyr` function `drop` or `filter` can also work, but I don't know which of these 3 functions best suits this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `sf` and `dplyr` packages, you can select the desired features using `filter` and using the "not in"(`! ... in ...`) operator.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

MultiPoly_Shp  %>%
  filter(!ID %in% List)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` and `%in%` within a bracket index, so very un-tidy like.

```
library(sf) 
( nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) )
  plot(nc["NWBIR74"])
```

Here, we remove the elements in sc.

```
( sc <- sample(unique(nc$CNTY_ID), 10) )
  ( nc.sub <- nc[-which(nc$CNTY_ID %in% sc),] )
    plot(nc.sub["NWBIR74"])
```

And, here we remove all elements except what is in sc.

```
( nc.sub <- nc[-which(!nc$CNTY_ID %in% sc),] )
  plot(nc.sub["NWBIR74"])
```

The `which` function returns the position(s) of TRUE resulting from the statement. The "!" represents "not" so, the statement is functionally "x not in y". The minus remove indexed elements in the bracket.

And, if you want the tidy way you are looking for the `filter` function, not `select` which only subsets columns. Apparently, not-equal does not work `nc %>% dplyr::filter(CNTY_ID != sc)` but, `nc %>% dplyr::filter(!CNTY_ID %in% sc)` does. Curious.

Comment: Should I be worried about the `warning message: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` that I get after running the `dplyr::filter` function?

Comment: And actually, the tidy way suggested in your answer doesn't get rid of the unwanted IDs mentioned in the `List` variable. I simply did  `MultiPoly_Shp  %>%
  dplyr::filter(ID != List)`.

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan uh, that is exactly the same thing, just substituting different feature, column and variable names. `nc %>% dplyr::filter(CNTY_ID != sc)` There is an expectation that you provide a reproducible example and since you did not I put one in my answer.

Comment: Yes, and when I did `MultiPoly_Shp  %>%   dplyr::filter(ID != List)`, it did not work on getting rid of the unwanted IDs.

Comment: Oh, I though you meant that your syntax worked. This `filter` syntax should work but, `filter(CNTY_ID != sc)` is not working where `filter(CNTY_ID == sc)` does work. Very odd. It does seem that the prudent tidy syntax here is `dplyr::filter(!CNTY_ID %in% sc)`.